# How should I use the new Optum drive?

Tags: cache, zfs, zfs-l2arc

I have a zpool consisting of 7 2TB HDDs of different vintage in a [raidz](https://pthree.org/2012/12/05/zfs-administration-part-ii-raidz/) setup. Currently, there is neither ZIL nor L2ARC device configured. The server has 12GB of RAM and no swap.

The different filesystems on the pool include `/var/spool/imap` and `/var/db/pgsql`. The users aren't many -- just family-members, but *sometimes* the usage can be heavy, such as when the anti-spam database is retrained (reading the "spam" folders under Cyrus-IMAP and feeding the PostgreSQL DB), or when a free-text search runs through all of the IMAP-messages.

I got a good deal on a new Intel Quantum 32GB device, and am wondering, how to best use it. One obvious thing is to add a [Separate Intent Log (SLOG)](https://www.ixsystems.com/blog/o-slog-not-slog-best-configure-zfs-intent-log/) device. But 32GB seems too much for an infrequently-used pool of 12TB.

The general opinion seems to be, I don't have enough RAM for a meaningful L2ARC. The current ARC-stats are:

```
ARC: 1680M Total, 441M MFU, 1113M MRU, 32K Anon, 31M Header, 95M Other
     1125M Compressed, 1942M Uncompressed, 1.73:1 Ratio
```

Should I split my new device into a smaller ZIL (4GB?), and use the rest for, say, Cyrus' indices and `ccache`?

Answer (score 2):

The ZIL SLOG device is intended for Synchronous write activity. This is used by some databases and also services like NFS.

If this is a server where you're running everything on a local ZFS filesystem, writes are going to RAM then flushed to disk. An SLOG isn't really useful for local storage.

Comment: Well, the PostgreSQL db is on the zpool... And so are the Cyrus IMAP-server's files, some of which may be written synchronously...

Comment: I doubt it. I don't think an SLOG device will help your situation.